# python sqlite3 update statement not working

Tags: python, sqlite

I lost 3 hours and I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. Please help.
I came to conclusion that it does not pass key as it should in update statement because I don't receive any error, but i dont get the db updated either.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('mov.db')
c = conn.cursor()
old_rows = c.execute('SELECT imdb FROM movies WHERE desc="" and imdb<>"" and year<"1997"')
result = c.fetchall()

for row in result:
    key = row[0] [2:]
    try:
    # Get a Movie object with the data about the movie identified by
    # the given movieID.
        movie = i.get_movie(key)
    except IMDbError, e:
        print "Probably you're not connected to Internet.  Complete error report:"
        print e
            continue

    print movie['title']
    if movie.has_key('plot outline'):
    m=movie['plot outline']
    print m
    print key
    c.execute('UPDATE movies SET desc=? WHERE imdb=?',(m,key))
    print c.rowcount

# Commit the changes and close everything.
conn.commit()
c.close()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are cutting two characters from the key here, that's why it no longer matches the key in your table:

```
key = row[0] [2:]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `continue` seems to happen on each iteration, so your `c.execute('UPDATE ...` line is never executed. Are you sure your code is indented properly?

Comment: typo, I do receive c.rowcount 0

Comment: @user1080711: please make sure to indent your code exactly as you run it. Indentation in Python is significant, and without correct indentation it's impossible to know what your code is doing